# How can I display an app logo in both Classic and Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, app

I'm trying to create an app that displays a custom logo. When I create the app in SF classic, the logo only shows up in classic. When I create the app via "New Lightning App" in Lightning Experience, I can only see the logo in Lightning Experience.

Is there a way to configure the application so that the logo appears in both places? Do I need to create two applications?

To summarize the issue:

1st approach (Creating an app in Lightning Experience):
Setup->App Manager->New Lightning App->Upload Image in "App Branding" section

Outcome:
Custom logo appears correctly in upper left in Lightning Experience.
Switch to Salesforce classic and the logo in the upper left is the standard Salesforce Logo.

2nd approach (Creating an app in Salesforce Classic): Setup->Create->Apps->New->Upload image using "Insert an Image button"

Outcome:
Custom logo appears correctly in upper left in Salesforce Classic.
Switch to Lightning Experience and the logo in the upper left is the standard Salesforce logo.

Comment: maybe you can share your current approach? where/how you are adding the logo? (code if possible)

Comment: I've now added the steps to reproduce the issue. No code changes were involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For existing apps that we wanted to make "Lightning Ready" we did create a second app definition. Each needed its own logo as the size specifications are different for the two UIs (300 wide by 55 high for Classic and 128 by 128 for Lightning.)

Also the image for Classic is a document whereas the image for Lightning is a content asset.